# How to divide a number without losing all the zero's?

Tags: groovy

In groovy I have a code like this :

```
def a = 44000
println a/10000​
```

which outputs `4.4`. But its eliminating all the zeros coming after `.4`. For some reasons i want the output to be `4.4000`. In groovy how one could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no significant zeros to the right of 4.4, it's not that it isn't displaying them, there just aren't any

What you have is a String formatting issue.  To convert 4.4 to a String 4.4000, you can do:

```
def a = 44000
println String.format( '%.4f', a / 10000 )
```